# Rundeck Mutiline regexp logfilter

Tags: rundeck

I'm stuck with multiline regexp logfilter. The following text is the regexp target

```
No such object (32)
Matched DN: o=yyyyyy,o=xxxxxx,c=cc
No such object (32)
Matched DN: o=yyyyyy,o=xxxxxx,c=cc
No such object (32)
Matched DN: o=yyyyyy,o=xxxxxx,c=cc
Lorem Ipsum lorem ipsum ydgsbahdjb:
- dsadjh dsajhdks uut75jf:
 hfdsjfhdj
 UTcnsbGHFGB885
 nasdx443t
SYSTEM-INFO: END
```

And the regexp used is

`(^(?!SYSTEM-INFO:|No|Matched.*).*)`

In resume, I need a multiline regexp that get line text that not start with `SYSTEM-INFO`,`No` or `Matched`.

If, I try it with key/value filter, got nasdx443t. It seems that multiline and key/value filter have different behaviour.

I want these data capture because I need to elevate this to a global variable to pass to another step (parameter form)

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest/quickest way is to filter using grep in the first step, then use the multiline regex data capture filter to create the data variable, and then use it in another step. I used the following approach: `your_command | grep -wv -e 'SYSTEM-INFO' -e 'No such' -e 'Matched DN'`:

Job definition example:

```yaml
- defaultTab: nodes
  description: ''
  executionEnabled: true
  id: baa28f4a-9832-4404-81b7-bee1b7fe9c0d
  loglevel: INFO
  name: Example
  nodeFilterEditable: false
  plugins:
    ExecutionLifecycle: null
  scheduleEnabled: true
  sequence:
    commands:
    - description: 'Print the output command and get the desired lines, then save
        that on a data variable'
      fileExtension: .sh
      interpreterArgsQuoted: false
      plugins:
        LogFilter:
        - config:
            captureMultipleKeysValues: 'false'
            hideOutput: 'false'
            logData: 'true'
            name: mydata
            regex: ^(.*)$
          type: key-value-data-multilines
      script: |
        your_command | grep -wv -e 'SYSTEM-INFO' -e 'No such' -e 'Matched DN'
      scriptInterpreter: /bin/bash
    - description: Just print/use the data variable generated in the previous step
      exec: echo ${data.mydata}
    keepgoing: false
    strategy: node-first
  uuid: baa28f4a-9832-4404-81b7-bee1b7fe9c0d
```

The first step executes the command and stores the result on a data variable, the second step just prints the data variable content.

Check the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64uu1.jpg).